# Run the same function for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, function, squarespace

I'm making a product gallery. There is a title of the product (an h3) and then a paragraph with the description. I have a span in the middle to hide part of the text unless the "READ MORE" text is selected. The problem is that the function runs for every product and not just the one clicked. If I select the second product, the first one is also toggled.

Here is the HTML:

```
<h3>
 PLS-CADD
</h3>
<p>The standard edition of PLS-CADD is a line design program that includes all the terrain, sag-tension, loads, clearances and drafting functions necessary for the design of an entire power
<span id="dots">...</span>
<span id="more">line. Also includes PLS-CADD/LITE and PLS-CADD/ULTRALITE, but not any of the other items listed below (compare editions).</span>
</p>
<a onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</a>
```

Here is the css:

```
#more {display: none;}
```

Here is the function :

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
</script>
```

EDIT: I restructured each product to look like this -

```
    <h3>
  PLS-CADD
</h3>
<p>The standard edition of PLS-CADD is a line design program that includes all the terrain, sag-tension, loads, clearances and drafting functions necessary for the design of an entire power <span id="more1">line. Also includes PLS-CADD/LITE and PLS-CADD/ULTRALITE, but not any of the other items listed below (compare editions).</span></p>
<a onClick="showhide('more1')" id="myBtn">Read more</a>
```

Each subsequent product's hidden text would have the IDs "more2, more3, etc...

My updated function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
 function showhide(toggleID){
   var toggleDiv = document.getElementById(toggleID);
   if(toggleDiv.style.display = "none"){
    toggleDiv.style.display = 'block';
   }else {
    toggleDiv.style.display = 'none';
   }
 }
</script>
```

Each description properly expands but I can't close them.

Comment: The code you have posted does not reflect the problem you have asked about. You have only one clickable element (product?) here and the function does what you have explained when you call it. Perhaps you could add a few more clickable "products" to help others understand more clearly.

Comment: I think @coderMonkey206 confused ID with class. Each ID must be unique in the page, while classes can be reused. In this case, classes suit better than ID.

Comment: getElementById should give you the first one it will find so, if all your ids are the same it should always work on the first product. Try to debug it on chrome, put pause inside the function and see what's you get

Comment: So I changed up some things and now the items correctly expand when clicked except now they won't close when clicked. I've updated my question to reflect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you had a couple issues here. You are trying to render multiple elements with the same id which is not allowed. Instead try the following:

1. change those id attributes to class attributes
2. wrap each product tile in a `<div>`, give each div a unique id attribute.
3. Pass the DOM event object to your function when the button is clicked
4. Use the event object to access only the elements in the tile that was clicked.

See the attached code snippet below for a working version.

Side note: you should use a `<button>` element here instead of an anchor tag. Anchor tags are only supposed to be used for navigation to different pages.

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  
  var product = e.target.parentElement;
  var dots = product.getElementsByClassName("dots")[0];
  var moreText = product.getElementsByClassName("more")[0];
  var btnText = product.getElementsByClassName("myBtn")[0];

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
.more {display: none;}
```

```html
<div id="product1">
  <h3>PLS-CADD</h3>
  <p>The standard edition of PLS-CADD is a line design    program that includes all the terrain, sag-tension, loads, clearances and drafting functions necessary for the design of an entire power
  <span class="dots">...</span>
  <span class="more">line. Also includes PLS-CADD/LITE and PLS-CADD/ULTRALITE, but not any of the other items listed below (compare editions).</span>
  </p>
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>

<div id="product2">
  <h3>PLS-CADD</h3>
  <p>The standard edition of PLS-CADD is a line design    program that includes all the terrain, sag-tension, loads, clearances and drafting functions necessary for the design of an entire power
  <span class="dots">...</span>
  <span class="more">line. Also includes PLS-CADD/LITE and PLS-CADD/ULTRALITE, but not any of the other items listed below (compare editions).</span>
  </p>
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly, you have `multiple` elements (cards in this case), for which you'd like to run this function? In that case, you can't use `id` because that is used for `unique` elements or elements that will be calling the same function. You should use `classes`, so it will be something like this:

```
HTML:
 <h3>
 PLS-CADD
</h3>
<p>The standard edition of PLS-CADD is a line design program that includes all the terrain, sag-tension, loads, clearances and drafting functions necessary for the design of an entire power
<span class="dots" id="card--one">...</span>
<span class="more" id="card--one">line. Also includes PLS-CADD/LITE and PLS-CADD/ULTRALITE, but not any of the other items listed below (compare editions).</span>
</p>
<a class="myBtn" id="card--one">Read more</a>
```

And the script would look something like:

```
const dots = document.querySelectorAll(".dots");
const more = document.querySelectorAll(".more");
const theButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".myBtn");

function myFunction() {
  more.forEach(more => {
    // THIS refers to the function caller - the button.
    if(this.id == more.id) {
       more.classList.toggle("more--active")
    }
   }

   dots.forEach(dots => {
     if(this.id == dots.id) {
       dots.classList.toggle("dots--hide")
     }
   }
}

theButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

And the CSS:

```
.more{
   display: none;
}
.more--active{
   display: block;
}
.dots{
  display: inline-block;
 }
.dots--hide{
   display: none;
 }
```

There's probably a better way and more dynamic way to do this, but this is all I could've think as for now. Hopefully this will be helpful to a certain extent.